# AWS sam initでのエラー (サンプルコード)

Tags: windows, aws

AWSのSAMのサンプルコードを実行しようとしています。

[こちらのページ（AWSホームページ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html)）に従いAWSのSAMプログラムのサンプルコードを実装しています。

**環境**
windows10
git : 2.26.0

`sam init` で以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Error: Please verify your location. The following types of location are supported:

* Github: gh:user/repo (or) https://github.com/user/repo (or) git@github.com:user/repo.git
          For Git repositories, you must use location of the root of the repository.

* Mercurial: hg+ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/repo

* Http(s): https://example.com/code.zip

* Local Path: /path/to/code.zip
```

sam init はルートディレクトリで行いましたが、上のようなエラーが出てしまい困っております。

ご回答をよろしくお願いいたします。
この作業ができずに困っています。
もしわかる方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？ [AWS SAM CLI x Windows10 環境構築](https://mukoiri-engineer.com/aws-sam-cli-windows10-environment/)

Answer (score 1):

> sam init はルートディレクトリで行いました

Windowsのセキュリティポリシーでは、ルートディレクトリへの書き込みが禁止されています。例えば普通に起動したメモ帳でもファイルの作成（保存）に失敗するはずです。

他のディレクトリを選択してください。

Comment: sayuri様 ご返答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘を受けまして、ルートディレクトリ直下にsamというディレクトリを作成し、 `users/sam` その中で `sam init` を行いましたが、同じエラーが発生しました。 どの階層で `sam init` をすればよろしいのでしょうか。ご教授いただけたら幸いです。